# Open Url with parameters only from a specific website

Tags: html, security, web

I have a website let say `www.company.com` that is accessible from everyone and I need to allow its access with parameters like `www.company.com?serviceId=2` only from a specific IOS APP and specific Website.

How can I verify where from my website is called and allow or not the parameters?

Answer (score 0):

you can send a `uniqueID` along with `serviceId` which is generated for each APP and stored in database on successful install.

**UPDATE**

you can optionally use

```
<?php
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']))
exit;
?>
```

This will prevent other websites to link to your page

Comment: Hi thanks, but this way if I get this id I can use it everytime I want from another website

Comment: I dont have control over the app and if the user gets the uniqueid he can use it from elsewhere right?